# Predicate of higher order: Split a list in two lists, one fullfilling the predicate the other not

Tags: list, prolog, higher-order-functions

I am trying to create a predicate which gets a list and a predicate. Each element of the given list fulfilling the given predicate should go into list 1 otherwise to list 2.

E.g.:

```
partition(>(6), [1,7,5,6,3,8], Rs1, Rs2)
```

which should result in Rs1=[1,5,3] and Rs2=[7,6,8]

I tried this:

```
partition(P, [], [], []).
partition(P, [X|Xs], Rs1, Rs2) :- 
    call(P,X,T),
    ((T=true, append(Rs1, X, Rs12))
    ; (T=false, append(Rs2, X, Rs22))),
    partition(P, Xs, Rs12, Rs22).
```

But for some reason I do not get the desired result. Why?

Comment: Here's the code: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/apply.pl?show=src#partition/4

Comment: I guess because `call(>(6),1,T)` tries to call `>(6,1,T)` and `>/3` is an unknown procedure. Unifying the last argument with true/false is not how `call` works or how `>(A,B)` works.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
test(X) :- X > 5 .

partition( []     , _ ,    []  ,    []  ) .
partition( [X|Xs] , G , [X|Ys] ,    Zs  ) :- call(G,X), !, partition(Xs,G,Ys,Zs) .
partition( [X|Xs] , G ,    Ys  , [X|Zs] ) :-               partition(Xs,G,Ys,Zs) .
```

Breaking `partition/3` into individual clauses that each deal with one particular case simplifies your code and makes it easier to understand.

There's also no need to use `append/3`. That can be done in the head of the predicate. That makes your code (1) more performant, and (2) easier to understand.

Moving the source list so that it's the first argument also lets Prolog index on it (another performance boost, assuming that it's bound when invoked).